# Determining edges that occur in all minimum spanning trees

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

Given an undirected weighted connected graph. How to determine the edges that appear
in all minimum spanning trees. I know the Kruskal and Prims algorithm to find
a minimum spanning tree. But how does one ensure that a particular edge appears in
all possible minimum spanning trees?

**My Thoughts**:
If an edge has degree 1, that will be for sure in all minimum spanning trees.
If an edge belongs to a cycle, then that edge will not be in all MST
I am not sure how to proceed from here, or I could use some algorithm to determine it

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2879893/580448).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all critical edges for minimum spanning tree](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93204/find-all-critical-edges-for-minimum-spanning-tree)